# An example of one-to-one function to two variables

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

I was searching for an one-to-one function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I failed to construct one. Neither can I prove that such a function does not exist. Do you have any answer for this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried to show f(x1, y1) = f(x2, y2) implies (x1, x2) = (x2, y2)

Comment: No, I mean which $f$ have you tried (and failed)?

Comment: It can't be a continuous function.

Comment: Well, since $\;[0,1]\times[0,1]|=|\Bbb R|= 2^{\aleph_0}\;$ , there **must** exist a bijective function.

Comment: @Burde: f(x, y) = x + y, sin x + e^y, e^x + e^y, e^x + log y

Comment: @Antonio: can you please provide a reference for proof? I want to know the proof.

Comment: @Wang: can you please provide a reference for proof? I want to know the lines of the proof.

Comment: I guess you know some functions $f$ that maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in a bijective way (those infinite curves, huh?). Think about some bijection $g$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (something realted to the $\tan$ function is valid). Then $g \circ f^{-1}$ is an answer to your question (although it can be hard to visualize).

Comment: a direct proof would be like this; first show that the set $D$ of digit sequences has bijective maps to $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ (decimal representation almost works except that some rational numbers are expressed non-uniquely, but that is a countable set so can be easily finessed); then take the map combining two sequences alternately and show that is a bijection from the product $D \times D \to D$ (easy), and then use previous point plus some continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ (tangent scaled for example would do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a trivial example, but here is a construction.  Often we make a chain of bijections between different sets.  This can make each step clear but frustrate people who want a clean formula.  I presume you have seen a bijection $[0,1] \leftrightarrow (0,1)$ so I will work with $(0,1)\times (0,1)$.  There are three bijections in the chain, one of which is used twice.

First we go from $(0,1)$ to binary bit strings.  The bulk of this is to match each string with the real number it represents as a binary fraction.  The problem is the pairs of binary strings that match to the same real-the versions terminating in all $0$s and the ones terminating in all $1$s.  You can handwave that away because it is only a countable number of points.  To be explicit, we will use the version that ends in all $0$s to match the corresponding real.  We have now accounted for all the bit strings except all $0$s, all $1$s, and strings of the form $[n]1111111\ldots$ where $[n]$ is the binary expansion of an even natural (including $0$).  That is a set clearly in bijection with the naturals.  Now pick some countable series of points, say those of the form $0.[m]01010101\ldots$ and use the interleaving trick you used to show the even numbers were in bijection with the naturals to account for the missing strings.

Now we go from pairs of binary strings to single binary strings.  We just alternate the bits of the two in the pair to get a single string.

Now we go from the single string to $(0,1)$ using the same bijection we used two paragraphs ago.

Finally we go from $(0,1)$ to $\Bbb R$, say by $x \leftrightarrow \arctan\left(\pi\left(x-\frac 12\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder (=CBS) Theorem in set theory, or directly with arithmetic of cardinal numbers

$$|\,[0,1]\times[0,1]\,|=2^{\aleph_0}\cdot2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\,\Bbb R\,|$$

Make sure you understand the above and can prove the different steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference.

Comment: Well, there exists a one-one function from [0,1]^2 to R. Is there any trivial example?

Comment: I can't come up with anything right now...and it must be a not-so-pretty example as such a function cannot be continuous...in fact, I think not even mildly non-continuous.